# XPC connection interrupted for Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am a newcomer to Xcode and swift. I am trying to build a tic-tac-toe app, but when I run it, nothing happens. The screen is black. Then in the debugging area it says: "XPC connection interrupted." I tried restarting the simulator and my computer. The same thing still happened.
Just in case you need it, here is my code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TicTacToe
//
//  Created by Will kaminski on 7/17/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Will kaminski. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!

@IBOutlet weak var Winner: UILabel!

//Buttons
@IBAction func Buttonbr(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttonbr1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttonbm(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttonbm1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttonbl(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttonbl1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttonmr(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttonmr1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttonm(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttonm1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttonml(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttonml1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttontr(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttontr1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttontm(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttontm1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttontl(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttontl1: UIButton!
//Buttons

let X = "X"

let O = "O"

var Gameover = false








//X and O buttons

@IBAction func Obutton(_ sender: Any)
{
    while Gameover == false
     {
    if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 1
  {
        Buttontl1.setTitle("/(O)", for: UIControlState.normal)
  }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 2
  {
        Buttontm1.setTitle("/(O)", for: UIControlState.normal)
  }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 3
  {
        Buttontr1.setTitle("/(O)", for: UIControlState.normal)
  }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 4
  {
        Buttonml1.setTitle("/(O)", for: UIControlState.normal)
  }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 5
  {
        Buttonm1.setTitle("/(O)", for: UIControlState.normal)
  }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 6
  {
        Buttonmr1.setTitle("/(O)", for: UIControlState.normal)
  }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 7
  {
        Buttonbl1.setTitle("/(O)", for: UIControlState.normal)
  }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 8
  {
        Buttonbm1.setTitle("/(O)", for: UIControlState.normal)
  }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 9
  {
        Buttonbr1.setTitle("/(O)", for: UIControlState.normal)
  }
}
}

@IBAction func Xbutton(_ sender: Any)
{
     while Gameover == false
     {
    if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 1
    {
       Buttontl1.setTitle("/(X)", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 2
    {
        Buttontm1.setTitle("/(X)", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 3
    {
        Buttontr1.setTitle("/(X)", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 4
    {
        Buttonml1.setTitle("/(X)", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 5
    {
        Buttonm1.setTitle("/(X)", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 6
    {
        Buttonmr1.setTitle("/(X)", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 7
    {
        Buttonbl1.setTitle("/(X)", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 8
    {
        Buttonbm1.setTitle("/(X)", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).tag == 9
    {
        Buttonbr1.setTitle("/(X)", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}
}


//X and O buttons





@IBAction func Reset(_ sender: Any)
{
    Buttontl1.setTitle(" ", for: UIControlState.normal)
    Buttontm1.setTitle(" ", for: UIControlState.normal)
    Buttontr1.setTitle(" ", for: UIControlState.normal)
    Buttonml1.setTitle(" ", for: UIControlState.normal)
    Buttonm1.setTitle(" ", for: UIControlState.normal)
    Buttonmr1.setTitle(" ", for: UIControlState.normal)
    Buttonbl1.setTitle(" ", for: UIControlState.normal)
    Buttonbm1.setTitle(" ", for: UIControlState.normal)
    Buttonbr1.setTitle(" ", for: UIControlState.normal)
    Winner.text = (" ")
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    while Gameover == false
    {
    //Winner X
    if Buttontl1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttontm1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttontr1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttonml1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonmr1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttonbl1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbm1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbr1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttontl1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonml1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbl1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttontm1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbm1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttontr1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonmr1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbr1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttontl1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbr1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttontr1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbl1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    // Winner X

    // Winner O
    if Buttontl1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttontm1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttontr1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttonml1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonmr1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttonbl1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbm1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbr1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttontl1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonml1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbl1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttontm1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbm1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttontr1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonmr1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbr1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttontl1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbr1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    else if Buttontr1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbl1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
        Gameover = true
    }
    // Winner O
  }

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.sweetoothdesign.com/games-tic-tac-toe")!
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: I did Vinod. It was because I had added a button as a label in Xcode. When I deleted it I did not delete it from the storyboard.

Comment: I suggest reset your simulator, seriously